# Update listview from API call in certain interval- xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a chat application in xamarin.forms.The viewmodel binded to my chat listview page have an API call , which will fetch the chat data and bind to the listview.The API will call only once ie; when we open the page. What I am trying to do is call the API every 10 seconds and update the listview if there are new messages.But what happening is instead of updating the list, it duplicates the entire data.I think it is normal that if the API called again, it will rebind the entire data. How can I make this update the listview if any new message available? like a chat APP works.Any help or guidance is appreciated.

The API data will be assigned to incoming and outgoing cell according to a parameter.

**My viewmodel;**

```
 public class ChatPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { 
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }
        public string APropertyToSet { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<NCMessage> Messages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<NCMessage>();
        public ObservableCollection<ChatData> ChatListObj { get; set; }
        public ChatPageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {

            // This is how I call the timer

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
            {

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await loadChatList();
                });

                return true;
            });



            // <--------------- Load chat List API-------------------->


            async Task loadChatList()
            {
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                    // API call is the dedicated class for makin API call               
                    APICall callForNotificationList = new APICall("apicallUrl/CallChatList", null, null, "GET");
                        try
                        {
                            ChatListObj = callForNotificationList.APICallResult<ObservableCollection<ChatData>>();
                            if (ChatListObj[0].results.Count != null && ChatListObj[0].results.Count != 0)
                            {
                                if (ChatListObj[0].success)
                                {


                                    foreach (var item in ChatListObj[0].results)
                                    {
                                        if (item.type == "user")
                                        {
                                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.message))
                                            {
                                                var message = new NCMessage
                                                {
                                                    Text = item.message.ToString(),
                                                    IsIncoming = "True"
                                                };
                                                Messages.Add(message);

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                //error message
                            }
                            }

                            else
                            {
                            //error message
                        }

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**My chat XAML**

```
 <ListView                      
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Messages,Mode=OneWay}" 
             Margin="0"     
             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
             SelectionMode="None"                                  
             FlowDirection="RightToLeft"                               
             HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="ChatList"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
             SeparatorColor="Transparent"
             >
            </ListView>
```

**My XAML.cs**

```
public partial class ChatPage : ContentPage
    {
        ChatPageViewModel vm;
        public ChatPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = vm = new ChatPageViewModel(Navigation);
        }
        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            await vm.loadChatList();
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing this for every message you retrieve from your API without checking to see if the message is already in the collection

```
Messages.Add(message);
```

you have (at least) three options

1. clear the entire Messages collection before calling the API
2. check if a message exists before adding it to the collection
3. modify the API call to only return new messages

Comment: Thanks jason for reply.How can Implement the second option?

Comment: If I clear the entire message will it look ugly? like message suddently dissapear or something?

Comment: use the IndexOf method or a LINQ query to check if the message exists.  No idea how using Clear will effect your UI, you will need to test that.  Keep in mind that if your API returns every message every time, each subsequent call will get longer

Comment: Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
            {

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    vm.Messages.Clear();
                    await vm.loadChatList();
                });

                return true;
            });

Comment: But it gave me index outof range exception

Comment: use Clear.  If you're getting an exception, it's probably due to something else in your code.  You'll have to debug it to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The usual chat systems work using Socket connections, so that server can `push` just the new messages that it has received, as opposed to your current `pull` based system. Take a look at `SignalR` if you want to pursue that path, here's a good example - [Real Time Chat App](https://mindofai.github.io/Building-a-Real-Time-Chat-App-With-SignalR-and-Xamarin)

As for your current code, there are a few possibilities:

1. As @Jason has mentioned, you could clear out the existing messages and add all of them again, you should use [RangeObservableCollection](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Controls.Issues/Xamarin.Forms.Controls.Issues.Shared/Bugzilla40704.cs#L149) so that it doesn't redraw the list every time you add a message
2. You could maintain a Id for all the chat messages and send the Id in your API call, ideally filtering should happen the server side, no point in extra load on the client.

```cs
new APICall("apicallUrl/CallChatList?from_id=<last_message_id>", null, null, "GET")
```

If there are no last_message_id, send all the data. This eliminates unnecessary data transfer, as you'll send only 1 new message than the 10k previous messages :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you guide me to clear the data? I tried to clear data like this

Comment: Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
            {

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await loadChatList();
                    Messages.Clear();
                });

                return true;
            });

Comment: But it will throw an exception about index out of range.

Comment: I used this Rangeobservable collection as you suggested. But clearing portion not working well

Comment: I dont think its the clear that throwing exception. You are creating a new thread inside async function which cancels out the BeginInvokeOnMainThread. To test it, remove the `Messages.Clear()` and run it, app should still crash.

Comment: Without Messages.Clear(),  the messages will duplicate and list will expand

Comment: Okey bro. Let me check